# Clearing cache using Zend Framework event manager

Tags: events, zend-framework, caching

I try to implement cache invalidation in ZF1. My idea is to add a listener to cache class, that will trigger invalidation in case of 'invalidate' event.

From what I learn in manual the correct way would be to add event manager to every class that can possibly trigger cache invalidation and then attach the cache class listener to it. But it seems like an awful lot of work to do such simple task.

It is possible to write it so that it works sth. like:
* any class can trigger 'invalidate' event
* whenever invalidate event is triggered the specified callback from CacheManager class is invoked and clears cache

Comment: is there a event manager in ZF1?

Comment: Yes there is since 1.12 I guess (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There what i did, hope it would help:

```
class Application_Service_Client extends Application_Service_AbstractService
{

    protected $cacheFormId = 'clientList';
    protected $index = 'client';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(new Application_Model_DbTable_Client());

        $this->events->attach('insert', function ($e) {
            $event  = $e->getName();
            $target = get_class($e->getTarget());

            $this->cleanCache('clientList');
        });
    }

    public function ajouterClient($data)
    {
        unset($data['csrfhash']);
        $id = $this->model->ajouter($data);
        $client = $this->findClient($id);

        $this->events()->trigger('insert', $this, $client);
        return $client;
    }

    public function formList()
    {
        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

        $cache   = $this->getCache();
        $cacheId = $this->cacheFormId;

        if (!($toCache = $cache->load($cacheId))) {
            $itemAll = $this->findAll();
            foreach ($itemAll as $item) {
                $key[]  = $item['IDCLIENT'];
                $value[] = $item['NOM'] . ' ' . $item['PRENOM'];
            }

            $toCache = array_combine($key, $value);
            $cache->save($toCache, $cacheId);
        }

        return $toCache;
    }

}
```

And the abstratct Class:

```
abstract class Application_Service_AbstractService
{
    protected $model;

    protected $cache;

    protected $events;

    public function __construct($model = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($model)) {
            $this->setModel($model);
        }

        $this->events();
        $this->setCache();
    }

    public function events(Zend_EventManager_EventCollection $events = null)
    {
        if (null !== $events) {
            $this->events = $events;
        } elseif (null === $this->events) {
            $this->events = new Zend_EventManager_EventManager(__CLASS__);
        }
        return $this->events;
    }

    public function setCache($cacheName = 'form')
    {
        $bootstrap = \Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');

        $cacheManager = $bootstrap->getResource('cachemanager');

        $this->cache = $cacheManager->getCache($cacheName);
    }

    /** 
     * Get a cache object from the cache manager 
     * 
     * @return Zend_Cache 
     */
    protected function getCache()  
    {
        if (!$this->cache) {
            $this->setCache();
        }
        return $this->cache;
    }

    protected function cleanCache($cacheId)
    {
        $this->cache->remove($cacheId);
    }

}
```

Comment: In your case @Tomáš you can make your main invalidation cache abstract